# Ubuntu 22.04 - packages broken after common update

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I have quite old instalation of Ubuntu, regulary upgrading to LTS. Last I did common package update via Discover I've got all broken.

Simple apt install got me this:

```
apt install firefox
...
...
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 installed udev package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd:
 snapd depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Fixing it with dpkg does not work either

```
# dpkg --configure udev
Setting up udev (249.11-0ubuntu3.9) ...
The group `kvm' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 installed udev package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev

# dpkg --configure snapd
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd:
 snapd depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
```

Even if I want to delete or install some unrelated package. Everything what I could find I have tried and nothing made a change.

List of errors grows depending what I want to do. But these to are always there.

Even with my 20 years of desktop experience and light linux/bsd admin, I cannot fix this mess.

Comment: "This question already has answers here:"  No its no, stackoverflow toxic as always, its a waste of time here.